# Converting .Bat files process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

two Bat files commands to convert into a PowerShell :

```
call "%CMD_Env_Path%\vcvarsall.bat" x86

call %BUILD_DIR%\TFBf.bat %1 %2 %3 %4
```

Comment: what problem are you having? ... what is your question?

Comment: set BUILD_DIR=%cd%\Build\Build_dir_Generic_GIT\generic
call %BUILD_DIR%\TFBtf.bat %1 %2 %3 %4 this scripts is required to converted into a powershell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please go through all of your comments, and edit your original question to reflect all of that information.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve Environment Variables in PS use:

```
$env:[environment variable name]
```

Example:

```
PS> $env:ComSpec
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

Comment: set BUILD_CMD_2010_Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
set BUILD_CMD_2013_Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
set BUILD_CMD_2017_Path=D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE
set BUILD_CMD_2019_Path=D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE
Set Make_CMD_Env_Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
call "%Make_CMD_Env_Path%\vcvarsall.bat" x86

Comment: This is steps which is needed to switch to PS.

Comment: set BUILD_DIR=%cd%\Build\Build_dir_Generic_GIT\generic
call %BUILD_DIR%\TFBf.bat %1 %2 %3 %4

Comment: What things is required to perform this activity

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to delegate to `cmd.exe` via its CLI (using the `/c` parameter).

The following assumes that that the first 4 positional arguments received by your PowerShell script are to be passed through to the `TFBf.bat` batch file, analogous to `%1 %2 %3 %4` in your question:

```
cmd /c @"
call "%CMD_Env_Path%\vcvarsall.bat" x86 && call "%BUILD_DIR%\TFBf.bat" $($args[0..3].ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f $_ }))
"@
```